# Intermediate value theorem on open or closed ball in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:R \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function, where $R$ is either a open or closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $a,b$ be arbitrary points in $R$. Proof that if $ d$ is an arbitrary number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, there exists a point $c\in R$ so $f(c)=d$.

Not sure how to go about this. I've tried defining function $f_{x_i}(x) = f(0,0,0,x_i,0,...,0)$, and then using the intermediate value theorem on these, and somehow combining the results from these functions, but that doesn't at all guarantee that $c\in R$

Comment: define $g(t) = f( (1-t)a + tb )$ where $t\in [0,1]$, then use convexity of $R$ and intermediate value theorem for $g$.

Comment: Since $R$ is connected and $f$ continuous, the image of $R$ under $f$ is a connected set of reals, that is, an interval.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  Regarding your suggested edit, note that $R$ is (perhaps confusingly) a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, so changing the title as you proposed did not make sense.  Some of your grammar/punctuation changes might be of slight improvement, and the OP will get a notice to review the suggested edit even though I rejected it.

Comment: Could you expand on the hayk? What is the convexity of R?

Comment: You've used the tag [tag:constructive-mathematics], but nothing in your question indicates you are limiting yourself to constructive logic so I don't think that's what you want. Also, as the [tag:analysis] tag indicates, you probably want to add a more specific tag such as [tag:real-analysis].